# Can't login to instagram from app - Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI

Tags: python, django, api, instagram, instagram-api

I have django app (Djnago 1.11) with `social-auth-app-django==2.1.0`

My problem is error: `{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}`

when I try login with:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'instagram' %}">Connect to instagram</a>
```

My settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_KEY = '#############'
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_SECRET = '###########'
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'scope': 'likes comments relationships'}
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/'
```

On instagram site I have also: redirect url set as: `http://localhost:8000/`